# Running into "Cannot find module" while configuring Babel + ESLint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, babel-eslint

I created a simple app a few weeks ago using `create-react-app` almost immediately I started getting this error in VSCode about it not being happy about something Babel related...which I ignored. My app works, I'm able to build and deploy to Heroku. And ESLint is also working. But the error keeps popping up in VSCode which has lead me down this rabbit hole of Babel and ESLint nightmares.

The error I was getting was regarding `babel-eslint` which I actually didn't have installed despite it being the parser named in my `.eslintrc.json` config. This is what my `package.json` file looked like prior to me making any changes:

```
{
  "name": "new-rails-react-project",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redbox-react": "^1.6.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.27.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./bin/webpack-dev-server"
  }
}
```

And this is what my .eslintrc.json file looked like:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "plugins": ["react", "import", "jsx-a11y", "react-hooks"],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "no-console": "warn",
    "no-dupe-keys": "warn",
    "jsx-a11y/rule-name": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-has-content": "warn"
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": { "jsx": true }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

Since `babel-eslint` is deprecated I added `@babel/eslint-parser` and cannot for the life of me figure out how to make this work. Here are my current related config files:
package.json

```
  "name": "ne-campground-reviews",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lightbox2": "^2.11.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redbox-react": "^1.6.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/eslint-plugin": "^7.14.5",
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./bin/webpack-dev-server"
  }
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "plugins": ["react", "import", "jsx-a11y", "react-hooks", "@babel"],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "no-console": "warn",
    "no-dupe-keys": "warn",
    "jsx-a11y/rule-name": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-has-content": "warn"
  },
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": { "jsx": true },
    "requireConfigFile": false,
    "babelOptions": {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is babel.config.js although I don't know if this file is still needed and/or configured correctly

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  var validEnv = ['development', 'test', 'production']
  var currentEnv = api.env()
  var isDevelopmentEnv = api.env('development')
  var isProductionEnv = api.env('production')
  var isTestEnv = api.env('test')

  if (!validEnv.includes(currentEnv)) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please specify a valid `NODE_ENV` or ' +
        '`BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", ' +
        '"test", and "production". Instead, received: ' +
        JSON.stringify(currentEnv) +
        '.'
    )
  }

  return {
    presets: [
      isTestEnv && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: {
            node: 'current'
          },
          modules: 'commonjs'
        },
        '@babel/preset-react'
      ],
      (isProductionEnv || isDevelopmentEnv) && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          forceAllTransforms: true,
          useBuiltIns: 'entry',
          corejs: 3,
          modules: false,
          exclude: ['transform-typeof-symbol']
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/preset-react',
        {
          development: isDevelopmentEnv || isTestEnv,
          useBuiltIns: true
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean),
    plugins: [
      'babel-plugin-macros',
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
      isTestEnv && 'babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring',
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        {
          loose: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
        {
          useBuiltIns: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        {
          helpers: false,
          regenerator: true,
          corejs: false
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
        {
          async: false
        }
      ],
      isProductionEnv && [
        'babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types',
        {
          removeImport: true
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean)
  }
}
```

This error is what's currently popping up on things like `import` and `module`

```
Parsing error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'
Require stack:
- /Users/maddoxgrey/Projects/ne-campground-reviews-v2/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
- /Users/maddoxgrey/Projects/ne-campground-reviews-v2/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/maddoxgrey/Projects/ne-campground-reviews-v2/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
```

Comment: Try `npm i @babel/preset-react` and check.

Comment: That doesn't fix it. In my dependencies "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13" is listed.

Comment: I might actually be getting closer to fixing this, I'm now getting the error:

`Parsing error: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'jsx, flow, typescript'`

Comment: Had the same parser error `jsx, flow, typescript` and could fix it by supplying the babel config file to the eslints configuration: in the file .eslintrc.js  add `const path = require('path'); module.exports = { ..., parserOptions: { babelOptions: {  configFile: path.resolve(`${__dirname}/.babelrc`) }, ...}

Comment: @Marc Consider writing your comment as an answer, this was actually a helpful solution to my problem. My error was "Parsing error: No Babel config file detected ..."